# Need a word to represent the opposite of busy

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Today I came across the Japanese word which conveys the meaning of having a lot of free time, and is the opposite of *busy*. The closest word which I can think of is *idle*, but that word seems to mean more of a laziness rather than actually lacking something to do. Are there any other words that would convey this kind of meaning?

Comment: I think that the phrase "at leisure" – as in "I am at leisure now" – fits best in most circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Free
2. Available
3. Leisurely (courtesy Andrew Leach)
4. Cooling one's heels

Comment: The first two are good so +1.  The second two... no.  Leisure[d|ly] is a very poor antonym for busy - at least is the US.

Comment: How about "at leisure"?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what the Japanese word is, or how it is used in Japanese.

Is this “lack of something to do” actually desired by the non-worker, or forced upon him? That is, is this *leisure* or *boredom*?

If the lack of busyness is leisure, then ***leisured*** would fit; if it’s boredom because he would rather be doing something, then ***bored*** would fit.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Inactive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inactive)?

> in·ac·tive  [in-ak-tiv]
>
> adjective
>
> 1. not active: an inactive volcano.
> 2. sedentary or passive: an inactive life.
> 3. sluggish; indolent.
> 4. Military . not on active duty.
> 5. Chemistry .
>      a. inert; unreactive.
>      b. noting a compound that has no effect on polarized light.

Or even [quiet](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quiet?s=t)? (6, 7, and 13)

> qui·et1   [kwahy-it]
>   adjective, qui·et·er, qui·et·est.
>
> 1. making no noise or sound, especially no disturbing sound: quiet neighbors.
> 2. free, or comparatively free, from noise: a quiet street.
> 3. silent: Be quiet!
> 4. restrained in speech, manner, etc.; saying little: a quiet person.
> 5. free from disturbance or tumult; tranquil; peaceful: a quiet life.
> 6. being at rest.
> 7. refraining or free from activity, especially busy or vigorous activity: a quiet Sunday afternoon.
> 8. making no disturbance or trouble; not turbulent; peaceable: The factions remained quiet for twenty years.
> 9. motionless or moving very gently: quiet waters.
> 10. free from disturbing thoughts, emotions, etc.; mentally peaceful: a quiet conscience.
> 11. said, expressed, done, etc., in a restrained or unobtrusive way: a quiet reproach; a quiet admonition.
> 12. not showy or obtrusive; subdued: quiet colors.
> 13. not busy or active: The stock market was quiet last week.

Answer (score 0):

In a metaphoric sense:

> Fallow: uncultivated for the current year.

More literal:

> Quiescent: inactive, dormant
>
> Furloughed: unoccupied, inactive (usually due to lack of work)

Answer (score 0):

There are exact opposites but the usage is not common as free and available in this sense.

**[unbusy](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unbusy)**

> not busy, idle, unoccupied

---

**[unbusied](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Unbusied)**

> Not required to work; unemployed; not busy.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer the words **clear** or **empty**.

> My plate is clear/empty.
>
> My calendar is clear/empty.

You can also say that you have ample **spare time**.

And normally used for machinery but used for humans too, if something is not in use it is **idle**.